# Printing large number of Points in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, printing, layouts

I have bathymetric data which have thousands of points ( exactly 71 K).

Now when I try to print it in a large map size in ARCMAP 10.0 , the layout view freezes and the system is hung , possibly due to a memory issue.

What is the best way to do this, rather than generalizing the points ? my preferred paper size is A0.

Is there a better software to do this ?

Comment: Before you assume a different software will do the job, what is the specification of your hardware (RAM, architecture, graphics card etc).

Comment: Perhaps include a screenshot of what it looks like in ArcMap too.  From what you describe I would not expect to have any problems, so perhaps you can describe each step you are doing to try and go from what you see on the screen to hardcopy.

Comment: RAM is key here.  Does it start writing to ur page file? Close all other apps whilst its processing.  Does it actually crash out?  Need more info.

Comment: Do you try qgis ?

Comment: Perhaps try converting your points to a raster file.

Answer (score 3):

A few thoughts:

1. Try adding your point data as a layer in a [New Basemap Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000017000000). 
   This will significantly improve rendering by utilizing a high
   performance drawing engine.
2. For an added boost in performance add your bathymetric data to a
   file geodatabase.  Rendering performance will also be greatly
   improved.
3. Restart your system to make sure the pagefile system is cleared and
   memory allocations are released.  After the restart, immediately
   open the MXD and try printing.

*Additional resource for basemap layers:*

[Basemap Layers](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/02/02/basemap-layers-new-at-arcgis-10/)

[image]

Comment: If the source format is a Shapefile add a spatial index, this improves displaying of data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is going to be to export your map to an image file first, with as low a DPI as you can stomach. Start the export before you leave work/school for the day, and let it run overnight. Do not click around your screen/etc - be patient - it will finish. We all know Arc is very fussy, for instance even listing a large directory of data can crash it (10,000+ files especially) but it will finish if you leave it alone.

As others are saying, you will probably want at least 2gb of ram for Arc alone; however even with 16 or 32, sometimes Arc just doesn't seem capable of certain jobs. I find that, even better than a lot of ram, is a lot of patience! Keep those hands off the mouse! Best of luck.